# css/js delegating scroll event on fixed elements to elements underneath them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, pointer-events

What I'm trying to do is have a block(let's call it `.top`) that is fixed and another block(let's call this one `.content`), that, when scrolling, goes over `.top`, this all while retaining everything that `.top` contains clickable.

Now there are some obvious setups

this 
http://jsbin.com/rucifuzu/1/edit?html,css,output

or this 
http://jsbin.com/hufomaxu/1/edit?html,css,output

problem with both is a) you have to account for scrollbar width b) scrolling/swiping on `.top` won't do anything with the element with `overflow: auto` underneath it

I have thought about a couple of solutions.

First would be `pointer-events: none` on `.top`, which would make it "transparent" for mouse events, thus triggering scroll on whavever is under it, the problem with is that click events won't work either, and since I plan on having clickable and selectable thing inside `.top`, it's a problem. I could reset `pointer-events` back to `auto` just for those click/selectable thing, but considering one of those clickable things is gonna be big ass headline, I'm gonna have a problem with scroll not working with mouse position on it again.

Second was what I call scroll delegation, using JS I would catch mousewheel events and change scrollTop on the `overflow: auto` element. This would work fine, except that it might result in different scroll "feel" while this delegation is happening and while native scroll on `.content` kicks in. It's also pain in the arse to get this behaving correctly on touch devices.

So neither is ideal. Have I missed any genious and simple solution to this problem?

### TL;DR Goal is to have the `.top` element BOTH clickable and "scroll-thru-able"

1. this way `.top` is clickable, but element under it **won't scroll** - http://jsbin.com/hufomaxu/1/edit?output
2. this way element under it will scroll, but `.top` **is not clickable** - http://jsbin.com/tuluwili/1/edit?output

Comment: I've been using iScroll5 and it's pretty good. http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5

Comment: @Diodeus I'm actually using iScroll for a different part of the site, but unless I'm missing something, it's not gonna help me with this..

Comment: Did you find the solution?..

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution @BrianHaak

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand 100% - you want to visually cover up a fixed element while scrolling but still be able to click on it?

One simple solution might be using 3 layers instead of 2.

Bottom layer contains your links and is fixed.

Middle layer is the one that will scroll over it and cover it up.

Top layer is fixed and is identical to Bottom layer except clear all the background colors and set opacity to 0.

When you scroll it would look like the bottom is being covered up but you could still click on the top invisible layer.

Might not work if you need to do things like drag to copy text or interact in other ways with the middle layer.

Comment: I don't need to be able to click on it while it's hidden, but I do need to be able to click on it while it's not hidden yet AND I need the scroll event to work on it(which won't, because the fixed element itself doesn't have any scrollbar).. check the examples, it should be obvious. If I made it so bottom(content layer) overlays the top layer, and use some margins from top to keep top layer will be initially visible, but then it won't be clickable(since bottom layer will be over it).. so I'm looking for a way to have both clocking and scrolling working..